# My subdomain routes are overwriting my normal web routes in laravel 7

Tags: php, laravel, routes, subdomain

Hello devs I have a project of laravel 7 in which I am trying to use sub-domain routes and I am able to do that but after adding subdomain routes I am facing an issue in which it is prefixing the subdomain in all the routes

**This is the subdomain route**

```
Route::domain('demo.'.config('app.domain'))->group(function () {
    Route::name('demo.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'DemoController@index')->name('index');
    });
});
```

**This is the main route (web.php)**

```
Route::group([], function() {
    Route::get('/', 'FrontController@index')->name('index');
    Route::get('/about-us', 'FrontController@about')->name('about-us');
    Route::get('/contact-us', 'FrontController@contact')->name('contact-us');
    // More routes.....
});
```

But when I am calling the **main (web.php)** routes it is applying the subdomain as the main domain

**Example**

```
<a href="{{ currentRouteIs('index') ? '#hero' : route('index') }}">Home</a>
<a href="{{ route('about-us') }}">About Us</a>
<a href="{{ route('contact-us') }}">Contact Us</a>
```

It needs to show the **domain.com**, **domain.com/about-us** and **domain.com/contact-us** but it is showing like this **demo.domain.com**, **demo.domain.com/about-us** and so on

I don't know what is the solution please help me with this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Your index routes have the same name. Try altering the route name on the subdomain:

```
Route::domain('demo.'.config('app.domain'))->group(function () {
    Route::name('demo.')->group(function () {
        Route::get('/', 'DemoController@index')->name('demo.index');
    });
});
```